# file manager not opening in every mobile

Tags: android, android-sdcard, filechooser

I am working on an android application  in which user will open file manager on a button click to select file either from Internal memory or Sdcard. My code is working fine on some smartphones but not on all .if anyone knows how to open a file manager programatically which works on all smartphones fine please help me.

Below is my code for opening file manager

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("/*");
Intent i = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File");
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_code);
```

Comment: Do you want  to open any file manager? (Like a select file button) or open a specific file manager app?

Comment: yes i want to open android file manager

Comment: You do realize that some devices doesn't have a File Manager apk installed right?

Comment: I am actually having problem on Samsung galaxy devices.I want to know is there any way for opening file manager,internal memory or sdcard which works on all devices fine.

Comment: What I'm trying to tell you is that if the device DOESN'T have any File Manager app it will not open anything (since it doesn't exist) so you need to check if those devices have any File Manager app AND not every File Manager app have the option to open a file.

Comment: ok got it , so how can i solve my problem? any suggesttion?

Comment: Elaborate your file selection class, it shouldn't be hard since you don't have to include all the options that a File Manager app have.